# Trouble with Safari css

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

Page http://sambuh.dai1y.com/custom.html
I've add tour to a basket. When I click to button "My tour" on the top, header move down to content. But when I move the mouse over header, it appears on his place.
http://joxi.ru/VrwW575fOKEXqr
In other browsers works perfectly

Comment: I test your page in Safari but i don't really understand what is your trouble, please edit this question with any screenshot and point what do you need

Comment: Please post the **relevant** parts of your HTML and CSS rather than providing an external link.

Comment: Sorry Katia, but i can't reproduce your issue, in my Safari browser works fine, doesn't seen like your screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown going Zigzag when hovering over them. Try using CSS only dropdowns instead of jQuery based dropdowns.